# Create drop down select in a view

Tags: drupal

I have a view, which is a table of a lot of content types. These content types have a status, that I want to be able to change manually and easily. For this reason I want to show a drop down select menu in each row of the table. How do I do that? Is it even possible?

I have attached a photo of what it looks like and where I want the drop down. Image of the view:
[image: Image of the view]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take the Watchdog view as an example?
Look into /admin/structure/views/view/watchdog how severity is managed.

Comment: The severity field in the Watchdog view seems to be a filter. I don't want to add a filter, but rather a select option menu, so I can change each items status easily